# packets getting missed when reading bulk data from tcp connection

Tags: go, tcp

Have tried both bufio buffer reader and ioutil.readAll  but it still misses packets while reading from TCP

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(conn, int64(pktLen)))
```

and

```
buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
bytesRead, err := reader.Read(buffer)
```

Tried with increasing the buffer size using

```
reader = bufio.NewReader(conn)
reader = bufio.NewReaderSize(reader, size) //big value
```

still no luck. can someone suggest what would be the best way to read fast bulk data over tcp. I have 2052 bytes of packet size coming over TCP continuously, need to read all packets and process them sequentially.

Complete test code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

type CStruct struct {
    Msg []byte
}

func processData(Ch chan *CStruct) {
    // Process the received data in another goroutine

    for {
        data := <-Ch

        fmt.Println("Processing data:", string(data.Msg))
        // ...
    }
}
func main() {
    // Establish a TCP connection
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to server:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    Ch := make(chan *CStruct)
    //start msg processor
    go processData(Ch)

    fmt.Println("Connected to server")
    // Create a buffered reader for efficient reading
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    reader = bufio.NewReaderSize(reader, 205200) //100 packets buffer
    // Continuously read data from the TCP connection
    for {
        buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
        bytesRead, err := reader.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading data:", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        data := buffer[:bytesRead]
        // Process the data in a separate goroutine
        Ch <- &CStruct{Msg: data}

    }
    // The loop will continue indefinitely, reading and processing data from the TCP connection
}
```

Comment: @CharlieTumahai added more code. please check

Comment: If you are missing data using ReadAll then reading the connection is not where you are losing the data. A TCP connection is a _stream_, you cannot read “packets”, and trying to do so is probably leading to some other false assumptions in your code.  The overall structure of the code, the double buffering, the statement that “packets” are 2052 bytes while reading 1024 bytes at a time (which doesn’t even divide evenly into 2052!) are all suspect.

Comment: If you have fixed length messages of 2052 bytes, then just read 2052 bytes at a time. Get rid of the extra buffers and goroutine (which is probably not needed) until you figure out how to read the data correctly

Comment: @JimB tried with 2052 buffer as well as single buffer.still same issue. GoRoutine is just to process the data separately, so that reader gets back to reading ASAP.

Comment: Did you verify that you read exactly `2052` bytes every time? If you didn't your framing is going to be off. TCP is a stream, there are no "packets" when reading. You cannot just lose data when reading from the stream without programming errors, but you need to define what exactly it is you expect to be reading here.